# Why is my overloaded "+" operator returning the wrong total amount?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

So i'm trying to wrap my head around operator overloading and I'm trying to add the lengths and heights of two instantiated boxes in main(). Problem is that the total should be myBox(2,4) + myBox2(1,2) = (3,6), yet the output total incorrectly displays "2 / 3".

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box {

    public:
        int length, height;
        Box(){ 
            length = 1, height = 1;
        }
        Box(int l , int h) {
            length = l, height = h;
        }
        Box operator +(const Box& boxToAdd) {
            Box boxSum;
            boxSum.length = boxSum.length + boxToAdd.length;
            boxSum.height = boxSum.height + boxToAdd.height;
            return boxSum;
        }
    };


    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Box& box) {
    os << box.length << " / " << box.height << endl;
        return os;

    }
    int main() {
        Box myBox(2,4);
        cout << "First box length and height: "<<myBox << endl; // Outputs length and height data member values.
        Box myBox2(1, 2);
        cout << "Second box length and height: " << myBox2 << endl;

        cout << "The total of both boxes is: " << myBox + myBox2 << endl;
        cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `operator+`, you're perform addition from `boxSum`; which is defalut-constructed just now with `length = 1, height = 1;`, then you got the result `2` (`1` + `1`) and `3` (`2` + `1`). You should perform addition from the current instance. e.g.

```
Box operator +(const Box& boxToAdd) {
    Box boxSum;
    boxSum.length = this->length + boxToAdd.length;
    boxSum.height = this->height + boxToAdd.height;
    return boxSum;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ey1rJ46o63fV1J0)

Comment: @Chipster: Why wouldn't it? `boxSum` exists, and so do `boxSum.length` and `boxSum.height`.

Comment: Nvm. I noticed you're saying the OP should use `this` which is *not* in the original code. I thought it was for some silly reason. I got confused for a second. My bad.